# hibernate with web service

Tags: eclipse, web-services, hibernate, jsp

before reading my problem this work in a normal dynamic web project
i create a web service like this methode:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2Vjs8ylmFM
using CFX 2.4 and with the 2.5 dynamic web model version and when i run hibernate in this current client web project generated by the web service i get an exception 
this is it:

```
  Etat HTTP 500 - 

     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

      type Rapport d''exception

      message 

      description Le serveur a rencontré une erreur interne () qui l'a empêché de satisfaire la                 requête.

       exception 

       org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Impossible de compiler la classe pour la JSP: 

        An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
        The type net.sf.hibernate.Session cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from         required .class files

         Une erreur s'est produite à la ligne: 16 dans le fichier jsp: /JSP/ebook/index.jsp
          Session cannot be resolved to a type
         13: <BODY> 
         14: <%
         15: 
         16: Session hibernateSession = HibernateUtil.currentSession();
         17: Transaction tx = hibernateSession.beginTransaction(); 
         18: 
         19: Etudinat etudiant = new Etudinat();


         Une erreur s'est produite à la ligne: 16 dans le fichier jsp: /JSP/ebook/index.jsp
```

and my class hibernateUtil is :

```
package DBase;

import net.sf.hibernate.*;

import net.sf.hibernate.cfg.*;


 public class HibernateUtil {

 private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

 static {
 try {
 // Crée la SessionFactory
 sessionFactory =
 new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
 } catch (HibernateException ex) {
 throw new RuntimeException("Problème de configuration : "
 + ex.getMessage(), ex);
 }
 }

 public static final ThreadLocal session = new ThreadLocal();

  public static Session currentSession()
  throws HibernateException {
  Session s = (Session) session.get();
 // Ouvre une nouvelle Session, si ce Thread n'en a aucune
 if (s == null) {
 s = sessionFactory.openSession();
 session.set(s);
 }
 return s;
}
```

and my hibernate.cfg.xml page is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration
PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-2.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory >

<!-- local connection properties -->
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/ebook</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">162826</property>
<!-- property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size"></property -->

<!-- dialect for MySQL -->
<property name="dialect">net.sf.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>



 <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
 <property name="show_sql">true</property>

  <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

  <mapping resource="DBase/Favorieensei.hbm" />
  <mapping resource="DBase/Ajouter.hbm" />
  <mapping resource="DBase/Favorie.hbm" />
  <mapping resource="DBase/Enseignant.hbm" />
```

and this is my page jsp

```
<%@page import="DBase.HibernateUtil"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %> 
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %> 
<%@ page import="DBase.*" %> 
<%@ page import="net.sf.hibernate.*" %> 
<%@ page import="net.sf.hibernate.cfg.*" %> 

<HTML> 
<HEAD> 
<title>Greetings!</title> 
</HEAD>  
  <BODY> 
<%

 Session hibernateSession = HibernateUtil.currentSession();
  Transaction tx = hibernateSession.beginTransaction(); 

  Etudinat etudiant = new Etudinat();
  etudiant.setUserName("davido");
 etudiant.setPassword("mioo");
  etudiant.setQuestion("best music");
   etudiant.setAnswer("rock");
   etudiant.setEmail("david@live.fr");
  etudiant.setNom(".....");
  etudiant.setPrenom("....");
  etudiant.setSexe("Homme");

   etudiant.setIDFilliere(Filliere.INFORMATIQUE);
  hibernateSession.save(etudiant); 
  tx.commit();
  HibernateUtil.closeSession();


  %> 


  <br> 
 <br> 
 <br> 
 <br> 
  <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="tableBox"> 
  <tr> 
  <td CLASS="bluebanner" align="center"> Greetings, </TD> 
    </tr> 
  </table> 
    </BODY> 
    </HTML>
```

this is my screan shot

[image: screan shot about hibernate]

plz help us we are running on time i have  3 left to finish it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>  An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
>     The type net.sf.hibernate.Session cannot be
> ```
>
> resolved. It is indirectly referenced
>   from         required .class files

Apparently there is something wrong with your classpath. Verify that you are importing everything as required (which seems correct to me on first sight), and that your hibernate.jar is in the correct folder and get loadet properly during execution.

Comment: we changed the hibernate jar and we downloaded another one Hibernate2.0.3.jar with net.sf.hibernate.Session but the sessionn is an Interface in this jar not a class and we get the same error plz can u help me

Comment: Did you verify whether the jarfile is in the current folder and gets loaded properly?

Comment: yes the jar is in the current folder ans it was loaded properly, i opened eclipse and i found the session.class there, but i got the same error

Comment: 'Found by eclipse' is not the same as 'found by tomcat', in which you are apparently hosting your application. Typically, you would place for libs in the WEB-INF/lib folder (and make sure they are deployed together with your application). I guess there are plenty of hits for 'tomcat class cannot be referenced' on google.

Comment: so i put the jars in WEB-INF/lib folder and i reference those jars in java built path? what did you mean with (I guess there are plenty of hits for 'tomcat class cannot be referenced' on google.)

Comment: Did you try whether that solve the problem? If not, please check on google, since there will be many hints for exactly that issue.

Comment: thank you it resolved that problem but i got another error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/beanutils/DynaClass